# Can Kafka nodes have different configuration(s) within same cluster

Tags: apache-kafka

I noticed that Kafka Admin API in Java allows us to see broker configurations by using `describesConfigs`. But it allows to see configurations by Node. Does that mean that each Node in same cluster/broker can have different configurations?

Answer (score 1):

Some properties are always different - `broker.id` and `advertised.listeners`, for example.

For others, it'll cause unexpected behavior. For example, the log cleaner could be disabled on one broker, causing compaction to stop working. Or the default topic partition count / replication factor could be mixed, causing unexpected downtime during app development if you don't pre-create your topics with defined values.

Comment: As said, for your own sanity you should try using the same configurations on all brokers. That said some settings are configurable per-broker, for example listeners or advertised.listeners. For that reason it's useful to be able to get the configurations of a specific broker. See https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#dynamicbrokerconfigs for more details